# completed an orchard tutorial on displaying a calendar but nothing displays?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I was trying to display some sort of booking system in orchard and I found a set of tutorials that allow you to set queries to display on different dates...

So ive went through all the 18 tutorials for orchard CMS 1.6 displaying a calendar on screen

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iv7rA-viyTw
```

and my calendar doesnt appear on screen? ive tried changing the widget of it (which selects dates on the calendar) and nothing appears, im logged in as authentic user, (as it is set to show-when creating the widget)

The only thing I can think of (which shouldnt be a problem but worth mentioning - in tutorial 13 where you edit template. when I tried to select a query none where appearing from the drop down list, I created a query as in the tutorials but still none appeared on the content page.) - this threw an error when trying to create a 'calendar widget' so I commented the code causing this in calendarWidgetDriver.cshtml.

```
//if (part.QueryId <= 0)
//{
// updater.AddModelError("QueryId", T("You must select a query."));
//}
```

But this only matters when you want to display a query on a date. surely it shouldnt matter for displaying the entire calendar. I realise this is a bit of a jump for a large Q. but im hoping on the off chance someone has encountered the same problem.

If so I would be glad to know.
thank you all

I have tried contacting the owner but as of yet no word so thought I would try here....

**EDIT 1...**

Logs

```
 2013-08-21 10:06:37,658 [32] Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager - No suitable loader found for extension "FoodPodBootstrapTheme"
2013-08-21 10:07:06,130 [32] Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator - ArgumentException thrown from IContentPartDriver by UMACS.FoodPod.Drivers.CalendarWidgetDriver
System.ArgumentException: queryId
   at Orchard.Projections.Services.ProjectionManager.GetContentItems(Int32 queryId, Int32 skip, Int32 count)
   at UMACS.FoodPod.Services.CalendarService.GetCalendarEvents(CalendarWidgetPart part)
   at UMACS.FoodPod.Drivers.CalendarWidgetDriver.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Display>b__2()
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClassf.<ContentShape>b__e(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\WORK\Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 130
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ContentShapeImplementation>b__14(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\WORK\ Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 139
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.ApplyImplementation(BuildShapeContext context, String displayType) in C:\WORK\ Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 39
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.Apply(BuildDisplayContext context) in C:\WORK\ Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 21
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClassa.<BuildDisplay>b__9(IContentPartDriver driver) in C:\WORK \Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\Coordinators\ContentPartDriverCoordinator.cs:line 49
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in C:\WORK\Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
```

**EDIT 2**

following the advice Ron gives at 7.40 of this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOSxGj2gOpY using 'Sources' from F12, he is able to view calendarWidget from inside localhost, i do not have this view able for me. What could i be missing?

Comment: Download his sample code and compare it to your own?

Answer (score 0):

The loader error means that Orchard cannot find the `FoodPodBootstrapTheme.dll`.

When i read ...

> No suitable loader found for extension "FoodPodBootstrapTheme"

... i assume it is a project located in ...

```
src\Orchard.Web\Themes\FoodPodBootstrapTheme
```

You have most likely added this project to your `src\Orchard.sln` file in Visual Studio manually and therefore the project is not configured for building correctly.

I had the same error multiple times and this is what helped me to get rid of the error:

1. **Fix theme build dependencies**

   - Open `src\Orchard.sln` in Visual Studio
   - Right click on the `FoodPodBootstrapTheme` node and select `Build Dependencies` > `Project Dependencies`
   - now make sure `Depends on` contains a tick in checkbox `Themes (Themes\Themes)`
2. **Fix Orchard.Web build dependencies**

   - Open `src\Orchard.sln` in Visual Studio
   - Right click on the `Orchard.Web` node and select `Build Dependencies` > `Project Dependencies`
   - now make sure `Depends on` contains a tick in checkbox `FoodPodBootstrapTheme`