# Nwazet.Commerce doesn't show in Admin Page

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I use Orchard 1.7.1, wanting to install E-commerce module.

I have downloaded the latest ***Nwazet.Commerce*** source code from **bitbuket**.
And I placed it in Modules folder.

Open **WebMatrix**. Click Admin.. There is not any menu being added.

ps.I have installed "Contrib.SecuredSocketLayer"

Question:

1.Should I change Orchard version?
2. Which way is the best to install module that has dependencies.
3. Which part controls Admin part in Orchard.. It confused me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: enabled it in the modules section?

Comment: Yes, all warning message has been sorted out.

Comment: Anything in app_data\logs?

Comment: I have same problem. In my logs: Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager - No suitable loader found for extension "Nwazet.Commerce"

Comment: @Jerome2606 It means Orchard cannot find the `Nwazet.Commerce.dll`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36793842/3936440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expected the same problem, I fix it in the code:

Missing reference for module Nwazet.Commerce : **Orchard.MediaPicker**

and you need to add **"using Orchard.MediaPicker.Fields;"** in file **ShoppingCartController.cs**

For me it fix the problem.